# Retain count of Array not visible in UITableView methods?

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, retain

I am having the following issue: in my application I fill an NSMutableArray with some data I read from the internet in XML format. In the same class I want to fill a UITableView with the data of that array. In the whole class - even in viewDidUnload I can ask for the retain count and it is even greater than 1 plus I can count the number of entities in the array (being greater than zero).

In the both methods giving back the number of rows in the table and the table cells the retain count is 0 and the count of items is 0 too.

I'll post some code as soon as I'm at home - but maybe someone out there already has an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I cam from I did not have a TableViewController added. When I did so it was able to access the Array with ease.